# Enviar un mensaje a n usuarios suscritos cuando se acerca una fecha/hora nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, crontab

Quiero poder enviar un mensaje a un usuario vía correo o sms , dada una fecha y hora por ejemplo 24/10/2016 14:00:00 enviarle una hora antes un mensaje , estoy usando para ello nodemailer para enviar vía email , y twilio para enviar vía sms ,pero la cuestión es como programo el evento para hacer lo que quiero , un usuario registrar un evento , y a partir de ese evento quiero que todos los que estan subscritos a ese evento , reciban una notificacion cuando el evento se acerca 1hs antes. 
Alguien que hubiese hecho algo parecido , le agradecería su ayuda.

**Actualización**
Uso redis para almacenar sesiones,y quizas pueda aprovechar redis también para usar cron-cluster ¿alguien ha probado este modulo , y que tal le ha ido?

Answer (score 2):

Con este código se puede ejecutar una función a determinada hora (todos los días):

```
"use strict";

function tarea(){
    console.log('acá va la tarea', new Date());
}

function lanzarSiempreALaHora(hora, minutos, tarea){
    var ahora = new Date();
    console.log('lanzado',ahora);
    var momento = new Date(ahora.getFullYear(), ahora.getMonth(), ahora.getDate(), hora, minutos);
    if(momento<=ahora){ // la hora era anterior a la hora actual, debo sumar un día
        momento = new Date(momento.getTime()+1000*60*60*24);
    }
    console.log('para ser ejecutado en',momento,momento.getTime()-ahora.getTime());
    setTimeout(function(){
        tarea();
        lanzarSiempreALaHora(hora,minutos,tarea);
    },momento.getTime()-ahora.getTime());
}

lanzarSiempreALaHora(21,10, tarea);
```

La función `lanzarSiempreALaHora` es la que agrega tareas/funciones. Entiendo que ya sabes hacer una función que envíe mails o SMS.

### Notas

1. Puede ocurrir un problema si la máquina donde está corriendo el programa tiene un cambio de hora. Si eso pudiera ocurrir esta versión simplificada no serviría (la primera vez ejecutaría la tarea en un momento incorrecto).
2. La tarea se puede parametrizar pasando una función anónima y utilizando los parámetros para fijar los valores (eso es solo necesario dentro de un ciclo):

ejemplo:

```
lanzarSiempreALaHora(10, 30, function(nombre, mail){
    envair_mail(nombre, mail);
}(nombre, mail));
```

Comment: algo asi estaba armando , pero la cuestión es que no saturaria al servidor ? , viendo que por ejemplo son n*m tareas que tendria que programar, he visto que con redis , podrìa hacer algo parecido , teniendo la ventaja que se podrìan almacenar los jobs , pero igual gracias.

Comment: No. El servidor no se satura por tener varios centenares de tareas. De todos modos, si en cada hora vas a mandar a varios destinatarios en vez de poner una tarea para cada destinatario se puede poner una sola tarea con una lista destinatarios. Eso reduciría la cantidad de timers pendientes.

Comment: También se puede hacer una prueba experimental colocando 100 veces más tareas de las que esperas (sin que manden realmente los mails, haciendo simplemente un log) para ver cuánto procesador y cuanta memoria se ocupa con esas tareas pendientes. Verás que no son tantas.